# Setup PHP Eclipse Editor for Linux on Windows machine

Tags: php, linux, eclipse

I want to develop PHP application on Linux(Cent OS 5.0). I have deployed Linux on other machine, and accessing the Linux server remotely from laptop(Windows 7).

I have installed Samba, PHP Eclipse Editor and putty on Windows to develop my application. Now,, since i am a newbie in setting up these tools, i have managed to configure SAMBA, so i am able to access linux directory remotely on my local laptop.

Now I wanted to know, how can i link PHP libraries into my PHP Eclipse editor, so that the development of code becomes easier and can use the features of Eclipse to full extent. Features as in auto-complete feature, etc. Any easy doc to setup eclipse, before starting the development process..

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I work from home on my Windows 7 machine is I installed the Helios Edition of Eclipse PHP and also installed the Aptana Studio plugin for Eclipse. This will allow you to connect to your codebase on a linux box via FTP. I would highly recommend if you haven't already done so use subversion or something similar to checkout a copy of your code because with Aptana you will be modifying the files you are connecting to everytime you save. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I tried once to install subversion, but didn't get any informative doc or material to make the installation successful, can you please help me on this.

Comment: well to install it on a linux box it's simply apt-get subversion. As far as setting it up that's a different story. 

Here is a link for the subversion cheat sheet I use:
http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/Subversion%20Quick%20Reference%20Card.pdf

Comment: The whole point of subversion is that you create a repository (your codebase) and check out branches of it to work on then you merge the changes back into the repository. This way multiple people can work on a single project without stepping on each other's toes, also you can rollback changes to the repository in case something screws up.